# Circle-backslash symbol at boot on MacBook Pro mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, startup, reboot

At reboot I get the circle-backslash sign on a MacBook Pro mid 2012 with an SSD.

The first time I pressed CMD + R and opened Recovery Mode from internet, ran Disk Utility and corrected an error on the EFI partition map. After the reboot everything worked fine.
As a double-check I made a reboot and the problem was back again. Tried a number of things, including resetting the NVRAM, resetting, the SMC, rerun Disk Utility (no more errors detected).
Every time i go into Recovery Mode I can just reboot and everything is fine. At the next reboot I still get the prohibition sign.
Looks also like randomly, after some power-off + power-on, the PC can boot back again in MacOS (something like 20% times ok and 80% ko).

I've disconnected the SSD and connected to a Linux PC so I could see SMART data for the disk. The disk looks in perfect shape with no errors and still 99% of available lifetime.
Also ran a Linux live distro on the MacBook from an external USB drive and performed a memory test without errors. The live distro works perfectly with no problems and boots properly every time.